# How can I write a simple gulp pipe function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've been trying for a day to write two pipe functions, one that compiles less files and another one that concats these files. I want to learn how to write transform streams/pipes for more complex plugins.

So I want to know how to read data from another pipe, and how to alter that data and send it to the next pipe. This is what I have so far:

```
 gulp.src(sources)
   .pipe(through.obj(function (chunk, enc, cb) {

     var t = this;
     // console.log("chunk", chunk.path);
     fs.readFile(chunk.path, enc, function (err,data) {
       if (err) { cb(err); }

       less.render(data, {
         filename : chunk.path,
         sourceMap : {
           sourceMapRootpath : true
         }
       })
       .then(function (outputCss) {
          // console.log("less result",outputCss);
          t.push(chunk);// or this.push(outputCss) same result
          cb();
       });

     });

   }))
   .pipe(through.obj(function (chunk, enc, cb) {
     console.log("chunk", chunk.path); // not event getting called.
     cb();
   }))
```

I can't get the `outputCSS` for each file in the second pipe. How can I send it?

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/dealing-with-streams.md might help some people.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Well, you don't need to use `fs` here, you already got the stream of file (here your `chunk`).

Another point, you're not sending back to the pipe the files, so I guess that's why nothing is called on your second one.

```
const through = require('through2')

gulp.src(sources)
  .pipe(through.obj((chunk, enc, cb) => {
    console.log('chunk', chunk.path) // this should log now
    cb(null, chunk)
  }))
```

In ES2015:

```
import through from 'through2'

gulp.src(sources)
  .pipe(through.obj((chunk, enc, cb) => cb(null, chunk)))
```

And for your specific example:

```
.pipe(through.obj((file, enc, cb) => {
  less.render(file.contents, { filename: file.path, ... }) // add other options
    .then((res) => {
      file.contents = new Buffer(res.css)
      cb(null, file)
    })
}))
```

This is still pretty basic, I don't check for errors, if it's not a stream and so on, but this should give you some hint on what you've missed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. What I understand from your code is that the file object contents needs to be replaced by a buffer of the css string generated by less, and in order to send it to the next pipe transform/write instance I need to pass this file as the second argument to the cb function. I will try this today and see how it works.

Comment: @vsync Simple _in gulp_, it may be easier in different languages

Comment: @vsync the word would be basic, not simple I guess. Most gulp pipe functions need to send data thru them this way.

Comment: @VladNicula - a simple answer wouldn't include any unneeded code (like `through` and so on) but only the most basic things, which this example does not show. So a person who comes from google, and sees this title, is looking for the very basic example and not 50% lines of code which are not related.

Comment: @vsync, are you using something else instead of `through` for this? If so, please write a better answer. It will benefit us all :)

Comment: @vsync I think you're crossing the line. The question is about how to write a simple pipe function. I've provided and answer to this question, if you want to know how gulp works, you should go to their repository. Stackoverflow is "only" a Q&A website you know.

Comment: where does `through.obj` come from? I tried requiring "through" but it says that `obj` is not a function. Do I need to npm install something?

Comment: Yes there is through and through2 npm packages if I recall correctly

Comment: Thanks! `npm install through2` and `var through = require('through2');` did the trick

Comment: @rob Nice, I will add it in the answer for future users ;)

Comment: If I use this and have .on('end', something) as the next step in my pipe, the 'end' never happens?