# Prettify JS on save using js-beautify with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, js-beautify

I am using [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) with Gulp to prettify JavaScript on save.

I am unable to use `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest` pipes. It was giving error

```
dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
```

So I used the following code and achieved the result I want.

```
gulp.task("jsbeautify", function () {
    const fs = require('fs');
    gulp.watch(config.srcTest).on("change", function (file) {
        console.log("Updating file");
        const destPath = file.path.replace(/\/[^/]*.js/g, " ");
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file.path, "utf8");
        fs.writeFileSync(file.path, jsBeautify(fileContent, {indent_size: 2}));
    });
});
```

The documentation in js-beautify doesn't provide examples to modify or write to file. So I used `fs`.

Is there a better way to do it? Maybe using `gulp.src` with pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you want to do with gulp, there's probably a package that already does it well.

It's the case for beautifying using [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) with the [**gulp-jsbeautify**](https://github.com/tarunc/gulp-jsbeautifier) package.

To [modify files in place using gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23247642/1218980), set the `base` option when calling `gulp.src` and use `./` as the destination.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var prettify = require('gulp-jsbeautifier');

gulp.task('prettify', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.srcTest, {base: "./"})
    .pipe(prettify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(config.srcTest, ['prettify']);
});
```

Then calling `gulp watch` will start the watcher.

> The "beautifier options" are the same underscored options used by
>   js-beautify. See the [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) docs for a list of them.
>
> All "beautifier options" placed in the root, are applied to CSS, HTML and JavaScript, unless there are no specific ones.
>
> The options given through parameters in gulp are merged with those
>   given through files.   The merge order is: default values,
>   configuration file, parameters.   Subsequent options overwrite the
>   previous ones.

This means that you can pass any default js-beautify options to the plugin directly in the gulp task.

```
.pipe(prettify({
  indent_level: 4, // applied to CSS, HTML, JS
  js: {
    indent_level: 2 // applied to JS only
  }
))
```

But I strongly advise you to put the options into a JSON formatted `.jsbeautifyrc` file at the root of your project.

- It's clearer that you use js-beautify
- IDE plugins can read it and integrate js-beautify benefits directly

---

*For more flexibility with gulp, see [How can I write a simple gulp pipe function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923523/how-can-i-write-a-simple-gulp-pipe-function)*

Comment: This means I can use all options of js-beautify isn't it like jslint_happy: true etc ?

Comment: @Maven yes, I added details about this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Does "@" completion work for you ? It is not working for me !

Comment: @Maven it works when it's necessary. You don't have to tag me because you're commenting on my answer.